# Backwards nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Normally people make nested forms where nested attributes are accepted for objects that 'belong to' the main object...

For example:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :models
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

So, given the above, one might expect to make a nested form for brand which accepts nested attributes for model.

This may sound ridiculous, but what I would like to do is create a form for model which accepts nested attributes for brand... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :models
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :brands
end
```

After in view make

```
= form_for Model.new do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %p
    Brands:
    - 4.times do
      = f.fields_for :brand, Brand.new do |bf|
        = br.text_field :name
  ...
```

This form will generate params for brands like this:

```
model: {
  name: "Shiny Ann",
  brands_attributes: {
    "0": {name: "Brand1"},
    "1": {name: "Brand2"},
    "2": {name: "Brand3"}
  }
}
```